# UITextView disappearing unexpectedly using iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, ios9

I've upgraded to work with iOS 9 and since then, one of my UITextViews, which sits inside a scrollview, is unexpectedly disappearing (this didn't happen in the earlier version).  The UITextView in question is part of a form that captures information that is submitted to a server. I can navigate between views and, provided I've  not entered and submitted information in the form, the UITextView is visible and editable. If I have submitted information and return to the cleared form, it is no longer there.

The UITextView is created in the StoryBoard and has it's delegate set to the view and is hooked up to the correct IBOutlet.

I have two other almost identical UITextViews (they appear further down within the same scrollview) that function correctly. This really is a puzzle!

I've set the background colour of the TextView to try to see if it has moved.  I've used the View Debugging/Capture View Hierarchy and it's simply not there! It simply disappears.  I have no code that removes the TextView or sets it to nil.

I'm stumped, so any suggestions as to where I can look would be gratefully received :-)

Comment: do u have any constraints set ?

Comment: No constraints and to make sure, I have added: [self.myTextView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];  I've also printed out the frame and it looks ok when I print to the console but doesn't appear in the debug view hierarch. It's a real mystery!

Comment: Can you print the textview's superview and/ or window? If it's not in the view hierarchy, then something must be calling removeFromSuperview.

Comment: Carl, that was the problem!  In a convoluted way, I was using a tag value to identify a different TextView in a different (non visual) class and it was removing the wrong one!  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for taking the time to help with this :-)